# Avoid waiting for the called task to complete

Tags: multithreading, task, ada

I got a question about tasking in Ada. I am trying to do a server in Ada that will serve multiple clients at once (using `GNAT.Sockets`).

Is it possible to dynamically create a task (with passing an argument) and not waiting until this task will complete? Do i have to use external libraries? I really got stuck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threads and semaphores in Ada95](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065136/threads-and-semaphores-in-ada95)

Comment: Got stuck? Show your code.

Comment: I mean i stuck with my research. Every tutorial about ADA i have read, tell me that i cannot start another task without stopping the current one(and wait for another to accomplish). It is something new for me (ADA language programming) so im askin if i need to use some external libraries to achieve my goal.

Comment: You don't need external libraries. You can create a task type, and declare an array of tasks of that type, and loop over the array starting them all, for example. This book is probably far more than you need... http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Real-Time-Programming-Alan-Burns/dp/0521866979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in your question, "Is it possible to dynamically create a task [...]”.

If you create a task *type*, you can create instances of the type using `new` and they will start running as soon as the allocation is finished.

There are at least two ways to pass parameters. You can constrain the task type (`A` in the example below) or you can pass the value to a `Start` entry (`B` below). If you need a `Start` entry anyway (to ensure the task doesn’t actually start before you’re ready), or if the parameter is something that can’t act as a constraint (for example, a record) that’s probably the way to go: otherwise there’s not a lot to choose.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Unnamed454 is

   task type A (Param : Integer) is
   end A;
   type A_P is access A;

   task body A is
   begin
      Put_Line ("task A running with Param:" & Integer'Image (Param));
      delay 2.0;
      Put_Line ("exiting task A");
   end A;

   task type B is
      entry Start (Param : Integer);
   end B;
   type B_P is access B;

   task body B is
      Param : Integer := 0;
   begin
      accept Start (Param : Integer) do
         B.Param := Param;
      end Start;
      Put_Line ("task B running with Param:" & Integer'Image (Param));
      delay 4.0;
      Put_Line ("exiting task B");
   end B;

begin

Create_A:
   declare
      The_A : A_P := new A (42);
   begin
      Put_Line ("in Create_A block");
   end Create_A;

Create_B:
   declare
      The_B : B_P := new B;
   begin
      Put_Line ("in Create_B block");
      The_B.Start (79);
      Put_Line ("exiting Create_B block");
   end Create_B;

   Put_Line ("exiting main");

end Unnamed454;
```

results in

```
task A running with Param: 42
in Create_A block
in Create_B block
task B running with Param: 79
exiting Create_B block
exiting main
```

then after 2 seconds

```
exiting task A
```

then after another 2 seconds

```
exiting task B
```